# Length Regex not working in ie8

Tags: regex

I have a simple regexp that don't work in IE 8.

Any ideas what to do to solve this?
My reges uses: `\"^.{4,}$"\`

Does anyone know how to make that work in IE8 ?

Comment: can u post little more code ?

Comment: Shouldn't those be forward slashes?

Comment: Post more code. How do you use it? And what do you really want do achieve?

Comment: this is what i have in my aspx file:
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexPassword" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^.{4,}$" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you wanted to write

```
var re = /^.{4,}$/;
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: "^.{4,}$"   is what i have in my regex

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to match a whole string consisting of four or more characters.  The regex for that would be:

```
^.{4,}$
```

You can write that as a JavaScript regex literal:

```
/^.{4,}$/
```

...or you can write it as a *string* literal, and pass that to the RegExp constructor:

```
new RegExp("^.{4,}$")
```

Does that help?